# QGIS layout variables not refreshing when changed

Tags: qgis, layouts, qgis-variable

I'm setting up over 100 layouts of different maps. I would like to control extents of layout map from one place, let's say via variable.
I tried a way using QGIS global variables but it seems to not work. I've currently defined 5 global variables - scale, x min, x max, y min, y max. I would like to see new output when variables change.

Is that a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

[image: QGIS map properties]

Comment: What are your system properties? Are you sure, that you have enough RAM for instance? The problem might be system-related for the number of records such as this.